# On installing seo suite in magento error is displayed

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

On installing mageworx seo suite ultimate extension in magento

"Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayer() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\View.php on line 134"

is displayed.

Even after deleting all the files that I had uploaded this error is displayed.

Comment: Did you clear cache after deleting all the files of this extension?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache

Answer (score 0):

Try to completely delete the extension. Follow the instructions given here: http://support.mageworx.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/74/4/how-to-remove-the-seo-suite-ultimate-magento-extension

Then install the module again. This is likely to solve the issue.

However, if the issue persists, please contact our support team:  http://support.mageworx.com/